# java script - Cant send parameter to function from info window in google map marker info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm showing up some markers on a map. when clicked, an info window appear. this window contains 2 button each send ajax request. the problem is that when I send any thing (Except a marker parameter below) to the button onClick event it does not work. and I get the error "adminmap.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on the first line of the HTML page not the script file at all.

```
function handleButtonApprove(id) {
    //error happens here when I send any parameter except marker8(defined below)
    //console.log(id);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: VERIFY_OBSTACLES_URL,
            //data: { markerID:sentID , approved:0 },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function handleButtonReject() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: VERIFY_OBSTACLES_URL,
            //data: { markerID:marker.id , approved:0 },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function attachInfo(marker8, num) {
    //var markerID = marker.get("id");
    //console.log(markerID);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //Here is the error , if I sent num.toString, num or any string , it does not work. If send marker8.getPosition() for example it works. May I know the reason ?
        content: '<div id="info_content">Matab Info</div> <button onclick="handleButtonApprove(' + num.toString() + ')">Verify</button> </br> <button onclick="handleButtonReject()">Remove</button>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker8, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(marker8.get('map'), marker8);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you like to provide a (non-numeric) string as argument to handleButtonApprove(), you must wrap the string with quotes:

```
content: '<div id="info_content">Matab Info</div> \
          <button onclick="handleButtonApprove(\'' + num.toString() + '\')">\
             Verify</button>\
          </br> <button onclick="handleButtonReject()">Remove</button>'
```

But this can't be the issue, because when you don't use the quotes, the error should be a undefined variable and not a syntax-error. What exactly is `num`?